# How to correct predicate on Prolog?

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

I have the following prolog code:

```
predicates
like(string)
clauses
 like(apple).
like(girl).

q :- like(A),write(A).

goal q.
```

How to get two solutions?

Comment: I tried your query with swi-Prolog (with some little changes to the code, since the Edinburgh Prolog sintax is slighty different) and it gave me the (correct) answer you expected. In swi, when a query has multiple solutions you have to type a semicolon after each solution to get the next one. Have you tried that?

Comment: Where should a colon? In predicates section?

Comment: In the prolog interpreter window, when it prints   
> Alexandrov - has 1 child  
you tipe a semicolon and hit RET:

Comment: When I enter, once again displayed "Alexandrov - has 1 child"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using findall predicate
http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node96.html

```
domains
Z = symbol*

predicates
like(symbol)
q(symbol)

clauses
like(apple).
like(girl).
q(A) :- like(A).

goal findall(X,q(X),Z),write(Z).
```

or using fail

```
domains
Z = symbol*

predicates
like(symbol)

clauses
like(apple).
like(girl).

goal like(X),write(X),nl,fail.
```